# error connecting asp.net to access

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This is the error i keep on getting.

An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

This is the VB CODE:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles
Button1.Click
Dim conn As New
OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OleDb.12.0;Data Source=" +
Server.MapPath("~/Access1/Connect.accdb"))
Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO Contacts( FullName, Password ) VALUES( 
@FullName, @Password )"
Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName", TextBox1.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TextBox2.Text)
conn.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
cmd.Dispose()
conn.Close()

End Sub
End Class
```

This is the Access:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awrAQ.png)

Comment: It looks like your application can't connect to your database. Do you have a MS Access database running locally? If so, how is it setup?

Comment: Isn't 'password' a reserved word in Access? What happens if you put square brackets around it?

Comment: Thanks men. After i changed the name password....it was working. i guess i did not know that 'password' was a reserved keyword.

Comment: @marcoteller  Following link would be useful for you in future -  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-E33EB3A9-8BAA-4335-9F57-DA237C63EABE

Answer (score 0):

As peterG mentioned, password is reserved. It's good practice to put all field names in square brackets (although I cannot recall if Access allows you to use square brackets) to avoid issues like this (at least from my practice), also it looks a bit cleaner that way in my opinion.